# a4j:jsfunction for jsf2?

Tags: javascript, ajax, jsf-2

I'm starting up a new jsf2/jQuery project, and would like to use the a4j:jsfunction in the ajax4jsf library. The problem is that ajax4jsf is not supported for jsf2. So I have to find some other approach to make an ajax call to the managed bean from javascript.

I know that jsf2 have some built-in ajax functionality, but not for this partcular usecase. Is there any other library that I can use?

I guess I can add a button or link or something, add an f:ajax for the onclick event, and invoke this from the javascript. However this is not an optimal solution....

Thanks for any help;)

Comment: There's none. What's the functional requirement? There may be JSF 2.0 ways.

Comment: I receive an javascript event from facebook when the user is logged in. When this event is received I want to call a method on a managed bean that will make a call to the database to get the userprofile and log him in...

Comment: maybe a solution is to make a call to a servlet that takes gets hold the managed bean and makes the call...?

Comment: i'm trying to achieve something similar and since the richfaces release is still under development I wonder if you advanced? Basically calling ajax from js is easier now with jsf 2, see jsf 2 javascript doc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

a4j:jsfunction is available in Richfaces 4.0 Milestone 4 which directly supports JSF 2.0.

Comment: i know, but I do not want to use richfaces. I could of course add the richfaces dependency to get the a4j stuff...but I was hoping I'd avoid that.

Comment: Ajax for JSF is a part of Jboss Richfaces.  It will be helpful for me to answer, if I know why you chose to avoid Richfaces.

Comment: I want to use jQuery UI for the gui stuff, which in my oppinion is much more lightweigth and easy to use.(and yes, I know richfaces uses jQuery) Also, I had several problems getting richfaces to run on glassfish 3 in an jsf2 application, though this was several months ago.

Comment: Which Richfaces milestone version you used with Glassfish?  Have you checked this? http://community.jboss.org/message/554323

Comment: ok..i've got richfaces 4 up and running and are able to use the a4j:jsFunction. However, it seems that the new a4j library does not contain the a4j:actionparam which I've used to assign values to the backingbean as the method is called by supplying parameters to the js call. Is there any way to include params in the new richfaces4 a4j lib?

Comment: Yeah this is not a complete release! There may be components missing.  Since you asked only about a4j:jsfunction I suggested this.